# Restarting plugin from PyQGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqgis, pyqt

I'm writing a plugin for QGIS and inside the method def run(self), after the OK button of the plugin is clicked, i.e., inside

```
# Run the dialog event loop
result = self.dlg.exec_()
# See if OK was pressed
if result == 1:
    .
    .
```

I have a test about some variables. If the test fails, I write a message using

```
QMessageBox.about(None,"Warning","Some text")
```

Then I would like to run again the plugin. I tried to execute the code

```
self.run()
```

after the QMessageBox, but the behavior is quite strange, because sometimes the same QMessageBox appears again and again.

How could I run again the plugin?

Comment: Use or look at the plugin "Plugin Reloader". https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugin_reloader/